# Kernel update destroys NVideo Driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel

The last two updates to 12.04 LTS have resulted in a no-boot system.

I finally discovered that if I SSH in remotely and re-install the NVidia driver that my computer will come back to life.

But now FireFox seems like it's running on a 33Mhz 386 - 2 or 3 seconds to change tabs.

My question: How can I restore my PC to the performance it had two kernel updates ago?  Re-booting to an old kernel does NOT fix it.

Comment: How about reboot to the old kernel and re-install the nvidia driver again?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is, first, install dkms:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

Then, build and install the nvidia driver.

You must either install `dkms` before you compile and install the nvidia driver or compile and install the nvidia driver each time there is a kernel update.

Of course, the easiest thing to do is install `dkms` so that the driver will update when the kernel updates.

Additionally, you could use the proprietary nvidia driver available through apt-get and you would also not have to worry about it.

For nvidia-304

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-304
```

For nvidia 310:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-310
```

For nvidia 340:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
```

Finally, whenever you have a problem after a kernel upgrade, you can always boot the old kernel by selecting additional options from the grub menu where you can select the kernel to boot from and don't forget that you can usually press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and sign in with your user name and password.